# How to build Docker images with the commit's hash

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-delivery

I'm managing a GitLab CICD pipeline which builds Docker images in a couple of stages and now I want to include in each Docker image a label with git's commit hash (see [label-schema's](http://label-schema.org/rc1/)  `vcs-ref` label).

I've noticed that GitLab already provides convenient env variables with that info (see `CI_COMMIT_SHA` and `CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` in [GitLab CI/CD environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/)) but I have no idea of how to include the info provided in those env variables in a Docker image.  Does anyone know if it's possible to include git's commit hash in a label?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the commit as a [build argument](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg).

For example, in the Dockerfile:

```
ARG CI_COMMIT_SHA
LABEL git-commit=$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

And when you build:

```
docker build --build-arg CI_COMMIT_SHA .
```

If you don't supply a variable, e.g. `--build-arg CI_COMMIT_SHA=abc123` then it will use the local environmental variable of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, use LABEL

```
LABEL commit_sha=YOUR_CI_COMMIT_SHA
LABEL commit_short_sha=YOUR_CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
```

Use docker inspect to get the labels from the images

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Labels.commit_sha}}' image:tag
```